# Prove that this function satisfies the contractive mapping principle assumptions

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $a$ be a fixed real number with $1 < a < 3$. Prove that the
> mapping $f(x) = (x/2) + (a/2x)$ satisfies the hypotheses of the
> contractive mapping principle on the domain $(1, \infty)$. What is the
> fixed point?

I need help, I got up to here. I made a previous post but the only answer provided was wrong. Thanks.

Let $x,y\in(1,\infty)$. We have
\begin{align*}
    |f(x) - f(y)| &= |\frac{x}{2}+\frac{a}{2x} - \frac{y}{2} - \frac{a}{2y}| \\
    &= |\frac{x-y}{2} + \frac{2a(y-x)}{4xy}| \\
    &= |\frac{x-y}{2} - \frac{a(x-y)}{2xy}| \\
    &= |x-y||\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{2xy}| \\
    &\leq |x-y|(|\frac{1}{2}| + |\frac{a}{2xy}|)
\end{align*}

I'm also confused. If $a=3,x=1=y$, then we have $3|x-y|$ on the RHS, and 3 > 1, so there doesn't exist a constant? And yeah I know we can't use $a=3, x=y=1$ but we can take really close values. Perhaps this bound isn't strong enough. Maybe I shouldn't take the inequality and work with the last equality. Is it 1/2?

What's the fixed point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the triangle inequality one too many times. $|\frac{1}{2} - \frac{a}{2xy}| \leq |\frac{1}{2}| + |\frac{a}{2xy}|$ produces a bound that is too lax. Instead work directly with the quantity $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{a}{2xy}$:

If $1 < x, y < +\infty$ and $1 < a < 3$, then
\begin{align*}
&0 < \frac{a}{2xy} < \frac{a}{2} < \frac{3}{2} \\
\implies &-1 < \frac{1}{2} - \frac{a}{2} < \frac{1}{2} - \frac{a}{2xy} < \frac{1}{2} \\
\implies &\Big| \frac{1}{2} - \frac{a}{2xy} \Big| < \max\Big(\Big| \frac{1 - a}{2}\Big|, \frac{1}{2}\Big) < 1
\end{align*}

Comment: Is the universal constant 1/2 then? What's the fixed point?

Comment: @beginner Modified the answer to show the universal constant. It is not just $1/2$ because the LHS bound $(1 - a)/2$ can be close to $-1$.

Comment: Ahhhh I see. Can you include the fixed point part too? Been stuck on that for a while.

Comment: @beginner Just solve $x = x/2 + a/(2x)$ it's a quadratic equation in disguise; also you can accept the answer to close the question

Comment: Is the fixed point $\sqrt{a}$? And is the general strategy to find fixed points to find the $x$ such that $f(x) = x$?

Comment: Also I thought one of the conditions of the contractive mapping principle is that if you have a contractive mapping $f : M \to M$, then $M$ must be a complete metric space but $(1,\infty)$ isn't a complete metric space

Comment: @beginner Yes which is probably why they asked to only verify that $f$ satisfies the hypotheses of the theorem but not to apply the theorem itself. They could just as well used the domain $[1, \infty)$, which is complete.

Comment: Okay, and, last question, is $\sqrt{a}$ right?

Comment: Yes and the negative candidate is not applicable because the domain is positive.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the triangle inequality in the last step. You have $|f(x) - f(y)| = \frac12|1 - \frac{a}{xy}| |x-y|$. Hence you want to show that $\frac12|1 - \frac{a}{xy}| < 1$ for all $x, y \in (1, \infty)$. This is $|1 - \frac{a}{xy}| < 2$, i.e., $-2 < 1 - \frac{a}{xy} < 2$.

The first inequality is $-3 < -\frac{a}{xy}$, i.e., $a < 3xy$ (using $x, y > 1 > 0$), which is true since $a < 3 < 3xy$, valid for $x, y > 1$. The second is $-\frac{a}{xy} < 3$, which is true since $a > 1 > 0$ and $x, y > 1 > 0$.